# how to display records in PHP from stored procedure Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I m creating stored procedure with multiple select statement,as shows below:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testsp` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testsp`(

)
BEGIN
select area_id,areaname from area;
select loc_id,locname from location;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

This shows as 2 different results..though i want to display different in PHP.
Php code:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("call testsp()");
  while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
   {
   $arr[] = $row['area_id'];
   $arr[] = $row['areaname'];
   $arr1[] = $row['loc_id'];
   $arr1[] = $row['locname'];
   }
   echo '{"users":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
   echo '{"users":'.json_encode($arr1).'}';
```

when i try to display $arr1,its showing null values...so how do i display second result sets in Php.

Comment: you have to do convert both query in one ie join or with from clause

Comment: thanks for ur reply.I want to display it in different different only so how do i do in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have one option use [union all](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)  to combine this 2 queries.

like :

```
select 1 as type, area_id as id ,areaname as name from area
union all 
select 2 as type , loc_id as id ,locname as name from location;
```

another option is to use a [cursor](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Working_With_Cursors.htm), 
loop over to sql queries by using cursor.

then INSERT the results of each loop into a temporary table and then SELECT * from that table when you're done looping.

Comment: If i use union all then how do i make different rows in PHP? Because some records are from table1 and some are table2 so...

Comment: u can use select 1 as type, area_id as id ,areaname as name from area union all
select 2 as type , loc_id as id ,locname as name from location; and according to the type u can recognize

Comment: oh ok thanks. then do i store type 1 data in $arr1[] and type2 data in $arr2[] in php?

Comment: with if statment , if($row['type']==1){ $arr[] = .......} else { $arr1[] = ........}

Comment: Thanks a lot it works.I hve 1 doubt ,to use Union All no of fields should be same?